# rails news feed with polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, feed, polymorphic-associations

I'm creating a social network using rails, the social has users that can posts pictures, comment on pictures, check-in places etc. 
I have created a table called activities that contains those fields :user_id, :ref_id, :creation_date, :activity_type, now I want to show friends activities to users, the problem is that I can't figure out how to retrieve pictures, comments etc through the activities table. I've tried using polymorphic but it doesn't work, plus I don't understand how to map the activity_type field with the right table

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user    
belongs_to :source, :polymorphic => true
attr_accessible :user_id, :ref_id, :creation_date, :activity_type

as_enum :sellable_type, :new_flag=>1, :flag_comment=>2, :place_comment=>3, :picture_uploaded=>4, :album_created => 5, :picture_comment=>6
```

and in the user model I have

```
has_many :sources, :through => :activity
```

this is how i'm trying to retrieve friends activities

```
Activity.where(:user_id=>friends_ids).includes(:source).limit(20)
```

where friends_id is an Array of user ids

Answer (score 1):

my solution is add a column to index id and type.

like "12@user".

you can checkout my gem
https://github.com/jjyr/my_feeds